# How can I access parent scope in laravel lighthouse relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

Laravel lighthouse doesn't access relationship scope like eloquent.

```
 class Tenant extends Model
        {
         public function products(): HasMany
            {
                return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
            }
        
            public function activeProducts(): HasMany {
                return $this->products()->whereHas('templates', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('id', $this->menu_template_id);
                });
            }
        }
    
    class Product extends Model
    {
    public function templates(): BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(MenuTemplate::class, 'menu_template_product');
        }
    }
```

This: `$tenant = Tenant::find(1); dump($tenant->activeProducts);` is producing :

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`tenant_id` = 1 and `products`.`tenant_id` is not null and exists (select * from `menu_templates` inner join `menu_template_product` on `menu_templates`.`id` = `menu_template_product`.`menu_template_id` where `products`.`id` = `menu_template_product`.`product_id` and `id` = 1)
```

Which is correct.

But when I call the same relation in graphql I get the following query:

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`tenant_id` = 1 and `products`.`tenant_id` is not null and exists (select * from `menu_templates` inner join `menu_template_product` on `menu_templates`.`id` = `menu_template_product`.`menu_template_id` where `products`.`id` = `menu_template_product`.`product_id` and `id` is null)
```

**Is the same query but instead of `id = 1` is producing `id is null`. In lighthouse `$this->menu_template_id` from within the `whereHas()` is null**

TLDR: laravel lighthouse cannot access `$this` in `whereHas()` on relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and use it as an ActiveProduct model.

Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW active_products AS
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `products`.`tenant_id` IS NOT NULL
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            `menu_templates`
                INNER JOIN
            `menu_template_product` ON `menu_templates`.`id` = `menu_template_product`.`menu_template_id`
        WHERE
            `products`.`id` = `menu_template_product`.`product_id`
                AND `menu_templates`.`id` = `products`.`menu_template_id`)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how. Can you please edit your answer with an example?

Comment: I mean: 
- create a MySQL view to get tenant active products
- create a model like TenantsActiveProduct
- add a relation to the Tenant model